# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.Driver

Tags: java, database, h2

I am working on a dB viewer for a h2 database in java.

I am using a sample code to try and connect to it as follows:

```
import java.sql.*;
public class db {
    public static void main(String[] a)
            throws Exception {
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.
            getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/test", "sa", "");
        // add application code here
        conn.close();
    }
}
```

But when I run it I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.Driver
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
>           at db.main(db.java:5)

Any ideas? I have installed h2 using the installer.

Comment: you need to add jar that contains `org.h2.Driver` class in your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Add the h2 jdbc driver to your classpath or as library to your project if you using an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you have not correctly added the h2 database as a dependency of your Java project.

- If you're using Eclipse you may use `Rightclick on Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Add External Jars`. Select the h2 database library JAR file.