# Seems my Junit test runs in runtime, the datasource missing

Tags: java, spring, junit, annotations, h2

I used a H2 database in unit test, use java configuration:

```
@Configuration @EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = AdvertisementRepository.class) public class EmbeddedDatabaseConfig {

    /**
     * Creates DataSource for an embedded Database (H2).
     */
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).build();
    }
```

and set scope to test in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.184</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

It's successfully build and in JUnit test, but when I run it on server, it reports error:

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.Driver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1274)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1108)
    at org.springframework.util.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:250)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.H2EmbeddedDatabaseConfigurer.getInstance(H2EmbeddedDatabaseConfigurer.java:48)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseConfigurerFactory.getConfigurer(EmbeddedDatabaseConfigurerFactory.java:39)
    ... 51 more
```

I'm confused: the junit test won't run in runtime, right? why my code automatically read the java config class, and not found driver class?

Comment: Maybe you accidentally use that test configuration also in production mode?

Comment: Add the h2 JDBC driver to your classpath or as a library to your project if you using an IDE.
Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29609985/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-h2-driver

Comment: @Nithin looks like the issue not in missing dependency but in usage of test configuration in production profile/code.

Comment: I had the same problem with IntelliJ, it could not found org.h2.Driver. I tried several solutions from the web but after a simple restart of IntelliJ, the problem was solved. Hope this helps to save some time.

Comment: @Nithin I guess he is trying to run the code a different environment other than dev... guess he will need to sort out the dependency

Comment: set scope as "test" seems have no effect, when I delete the scope=test line, it works. but it not very likely I think, for it's load in runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I will not be able to point out the exact issue, the problem you are facing is that org.h2.Driver is not available while trying to run the test. As mentioned in one of the comments make sure that jar is available in the classpath.

PS: If you are using an Ant build and trying to run test before deploying to production, make sure the jar is available before ANT runs your tests.